# Don't understand the difference between $P(a \le X \le b)$ and $P(X\in B)$

Tags: probability

By def, $P(a \le X \le b)=\int_a^b f_X(x) dx$ and $P(X\in B)=\int_B f_X(x) dx$.

I think I understand $P(a \le X \le b)$ well enough: it tells you that if $X$ is the random variable that maps the height of someone to $x$, then $P(a \le X \le b)$ asks what's the probability of someone's height, or $x$, being between $a$ and $b$.

$P(X\in B)$ is a lot more confusing. My textbook, Tsitsiklis' *Intro to Probability and Statistics*, said this is 'the PDF of $X$ for every subset $B$ of the real line'.

I have no idea what that is supposed to mean. Is it just the probability of $x$ being a real number?

The integral also doesn't make much sense to me. I can understand what $\int_a^b$ means - the area under the function between $x=a$ and $x=b$. But $\int_B$ only gives the lower bound...I am sure it doesn't mean the area from $B$ to infinite...so what does it mean?

Comment: They are the same when $B$ is the interval $[a.b]=\{x:a\le x\le b\}$.

Comment: $B$ can be any proper (i.e. measurable) subset of the reals. Namely, it could be $(a,b) \cup (c,d)$. Then $P(X\in B) = P(a<X<b \ \text{or} \ c<X<d)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$B$ in the statement $P(X\in B)$ is a **subset** of $\mathbb R$.

In fact, you can rewrite $P(a\leq X\leq B)$ as $$P(X\in [a, b])$$ in which case you can use the second definition to get, $$P(X\in [a, b]) = \int_{[a,b]}f_X(x)dx$$

and, "luckily", measure theory also tells you that

$$\int_{[a,b]}f_X(x)dx = \int_a^bf_X(x)dx$$

so the two definitions are compatible.